# Using ResolveClientUrl() in external JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I found that ResolveClientUrl() works as expected when JavaScript is embedded in ASPX page, however it doesn't resolve anything when external script is referenced in ASPX like this:

```
<script src="../Javascript/sessionManagement.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there a way to make ResolveClientUrl() work in external JS files? I was expected that it would because this file IS included in ASPX page but this is not the case.

I found a rather ugly workaround - to include external JS file in ASPX page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="jscript">
    <!--#include file="../Javascript/sessionManagement.js"-->
</script>
```

It works (ResolveClientUrl() actually resolves path) but I've never seen external JS files referenced like that and am not sure this is the way to go.

Comment: Your .js files are not processed as `.aspx` pages, you can't run inline C# or VB code on them. Instead, run it directly on the .aspx page and then access that variable from your JS, or pass it through a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myUrl = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("MyURL") %>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/sssionManagement.js"></script>
```

and in your **sessionManagement.js**, you can simply use the **myUrl** variable above